# How do I enable all error messages altering directly a database table?

Tags: database, 9

When I try to log in on a site, I get a generic error, which doesn't help in understanding what exactly is going wrong.

I would like to enable the *All messages, with backtrace information* option shown for *Error messages to display*, to be able to understand what the error cause is.

Is it possible to change it by directly altering a database table? If the answer is *yes*, which table and which row should I change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question as written, "directly in MySQL", is unanswerable. The value to change is found with this query:

```
SELECT data FROM `config` where name = 'system.logging';
```

But the content of the `data` column is a blob type containing serialized PHP data, and that data contains a configuration hash that is particular to your site.

You will have to write a PHP program that selects the value, unserializes it, changes the `error_level` key to `verbose`, serializes the new data then re-inserts it. I know of now way to do that directly in MySQL alone.